# Redirect of STDERR not closing

Tags: windows, perl, file-io

I am redirecting STDERR to an error file but am unable to unlink the error file if it is empty.  I believe that I am not releasing STDERR which is rendering the error file busy and cannot be deleted.  What do you think?  Thank you!

```
$errFile = $outFile . "-error";
open (ERRFILE, '>', $errFile) or die $!;

#Redirect STDERR from the console to the error log
open (STDERR, '>', $errFile) or die $!;

# Do stuff....

close(STDERR);
close(ERRFILE);

#Remove blank error files
opendir(DIR, 'c:\LMITS');
@errFiles = grep /error/, readdir DIR;
closedir DIR;

foreach $errFile (@errFiles) {
    $errFileSize = -s $errFile;
    if ($errFileSize == 0) {
        unlink $errFile;
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, you should always use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`.

Comment: Also, you're opening two filehandles to the same file in truncate mode. One of them will lose. ;-)

Comment: Thanks gents.  I'm using strict and warnings but not warnings (all).  Fixed that.  I'm not sure what happened but it seems to be working now.  Possibly the file was marked busy for another reason?  I don't think I had it open in another.  Thank you.

Comment: You should also check `unlink` for failure to make sure the deletion actually happened. But don't `die` with `$!`, because you closed `STDERR` a few lines prior!

Comment: Good point Matt, I will add that.  Thank you very much for the advice!

Comment: I was just able to reproduce the problem again.  When I close STDERR and ERRFILE a few lines up in my script I am fine.  But when that processing is done immediately before I try to do my delete then it fails.  I wonder if I need to put a pause in because my script it stepping on itself.  Almost like the unlink cannot happen because the close has not yet completed....hmmmmm

Comment: Re "I'm using strict", There's no way the code you posted would run with strict.

Comment: Ikegami please see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readdir` returns file names, not paths.

```
foreach  (@errFiles) {
    my $errFile = 'c:\\LMITS\\' . $_;
    ...
}
```

Comment: ikegami, the foreach is working fine.  I'm populating the array with filenames and then checking to see if they are empty.

Comment: I didn't change the loop; I changed `$errFile`. You list the contents of `C:\LMITS`, but you delete files in `.`.

Comment: Ahhhhh good catch.  My script is running out of C;\LMITS so it just works.  But your right Im being inconsistent.  And I could have a problem when I move the script to the production server and put it in CRON/scheduled task.  Thank you so much for finding that!

Comment: Ikegami, I have it working but Im getting weird results when I move the STDERR and ERRFILE close down any.  I'm good to go but will researching why just so I know for next time.

Answer (score 0):

This code works but if I move the commands to close SDTERR and ERRFILE down in the script any a blank ERRFILE will not be deleted.  I'm ok for now but I will keep researching for the sake of just knowing.

```
use CQPerlExt;
use POSIX qw(strftime);
use Strict;

my $checkForBlanks;
my $dbConfig;
my $dbConfigRecord;
my $entitydef;
my $errFile;
my @errFiles;
my $errFileSize;
my $fileDate;
my @fieldNames;
my $fieldName;
my $lastSync;
my $outFile;
my $queryDef;
my $queryResults;
my $recordCount = 0;
my $recordType;
my $session;
my $scriptStartTime;
my $swCR;
my $swData;
my $swID;

# ##############################################
# ##### Process administrative items and 
# ##### establish a ClearQuest session
# ##############################################

$scriptStartTime = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p", localtime());
$fileDate = strftime("%Y%m%d_%I%M%S%p", localtime());

#Create and open the output and error files
$outFile = "MSTU_Unclass_Export"."_".$fileDate.".txt"; 
open (OUTFILE, ">", $outFile) or die $!;
$errFile = $outFile . "-error";
open (ERRFILE, '>', $errFile) or die $!;

#Redirect STDERR from the console to the error log
open (STDERR, '>', $errFile) or die $!;

$session = CQSession::Build();
CQSession::UserLogon($session, "uname", "pw", "db", "schema");  

$dbConfigRecord = $session->GetEntity("DB_CONFIG", "33554467");
$lastSync = $dbConfigRecord->GetFieldStringValue("LastSyncDate");

# ##############################################
# ##### Query the database for all SWCRs
# ##### updated after lastSyncDate
# ##############################################

$queryDef = $session->BuildQuery("SWCR");
$queryDef->BuildField("dbid");

@lastSyncDate = ($lastSync);
$operator = $queryDef->BuildFilterOperator($CQPerlExt::CQ_BOOL_OP_AND);
$operator->BuildFilter ("history.action_timestamp", $CQPerlExt::CQ_COMP_OP_GTE,\@lastSyncDate); 

$queryResults = $session->BuildResultSet($queryDef);
$queryResults->Execute();

# ##############################################
# ##### Build a text file with SWCR data associated
# ##### with the dbids returned above
# ##############################################

#Get all of the fieldnames you want to export
$recordType = 'SWCR';
$entitydef = $session->GetEntityDef($recordType);
@fieldNames = @{$entitydef->GetFieldDefNames()};

#Remove any fields you don't want
@fieldNames = grep ! /dbid|history|RecordID|CCObjects|MergeSWCRs|AssociatedIntegrationSet|Level1TestResults|
                     Level2TestResults|Level3TestResults|Level4TestResults|Reviews|WithdrawCR|
                     AssociatedWithdrawnCR|Attachments|AssociatedPRs|OriginatingSolution|AssociatedSWRsFull|
                     AssociatedSWRsDelta|ClonedFrom|ClonedTo|AssociatedComment|ExternalLinks|ratl_mastership/x, @fieldNames;

while ($queryResults->MoveNext() == $CQPerlExt::CQ_SUCCESS) {
        $swCR = $session->GetEntityByDbId("SWCR", $queryResults->GetColumnValue(1));

        #Gather data        
        $swID = $swCR->GetFieldValue("RecordID")->GetValue();
        $swData = "<RecordID>" . $swID . "</RecordID>";
            foreach $fieldName (@fieldNames)
                {
                $checkForBlanks = $swCR->GetFieldStringValue($fieldName);
                if ($checkForBlanks ne ""){
                $swData = $swData . "<" . $fieldName . ">" . $swCR->GetFieldStringValue($fieldName) . "</" . $fieldName . ">";
                                          }
                            }

        #Build file with records seperated by custom line delimiter
        print OUTFILE $swData . "~~lineDelimiter~~\n";
        #Keep track of the amount of records being exported
        $recordCount++;
                                 }

close(STDERR);
close(ERRFILE);
close(OUTFILE);

# ##############################################
# ##### Process administrative items and 
# ##### close ClearQuest session
# ##############################################

#Remove extra carriage return at bottom of export file because this will throw an error when an import is performed
truncate($outFile, (-s $outFile) - 2);

#Add amount of records exported to the export log
open (EXPLOG, ">>", 'Export_Log.txt') or die $!; 
print EXPLOG "$scriptStartTime: $recordCount record(s) written to $outFile for export.\n";
close (EXPLOG);

#Set the LastSyncDate field to the time the export script started
$dbConfigRecord = $session->GetEntity("DB_CONFIG", "33554467");
$session->EditEntity($dbConfigRecord, "Modify");
$dbConfigRecord->SetFieldValue("LastSyncDate",$scriptStartTime);
$dbConfigRecord->Validate();
$dbConfigRecord->Commit();

#Remove blank error files
opendir(DIR, 'c:\LMITS');
@errFiles = grep /error/, readdir DIR;
closedir DIR;

    foreach $errFile (@errFiles) {
        $errFileSize = -s $errFile;
        if ($errFileSize == 0) {
        unlink $errFile;
                       }
                     }

CQSession::Unbuild($session);
```